# Tensorflow lite Interpreter crash when run after resizeInput()

Tags: java, android, tensorflow-lite

I have a tensorflow lite model which use,
input is **{1,320,320,3}**
output array dataType is {FLOAT32,FLOAT32,INT32}.
Interpreter#runForMultipleInputsOutputs crashed when resized the input to **{1,224,320,3}**.

My tensorflow lite version:

```
    implementation('org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly') { changing = true }
    implementation('org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:0.0.0-nightly') { changing = true }
    implementation('org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.0.0-nightly') { changing = true }
```

Create the input tensor. Prepare the output tensor:

```
        inputImageBuffer = new TensorImage(imageDataType);
        outputArr = new TensorBuffer[tflite.getOutputTensorCount()];
        resizeOutputArr = new TensorBuffer[tflite.getOutputTensorCount()];
        for (int i = 0, count = tflite.getOutputTensorCount(); i < count; i++) {
            DataType pDataType = tflite.getOutputTensor(i).dataType();
            if (pDataType == DataType.INT32) pDataType = DataType.FLOAT32;
            outputArr[i] = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(i == 0 ? new int[]{imageSizeY, imageSizeX} : new int[]{imageSizeX}, pDataType);
            resizeOutputArr[i] = TensorBuffer.createDynamic(pDataType);
        }
```

Resize the input imagebuffer

```
        // Loads bitmap into a TensorImage.
        inputImageBuffer.load(bitmap);
        float sc = bitmap.getWidth() / 320.0f;
        int scaleWid = Math.round(bitmap.getWidth() / sc);
        int scaleHei = Math.round(bitmap.getHeight() / sc);
        imageSizeY = scaleHei / 32 * 32;
        // Creates processor for the TensorImage.
        int numRotation = sensorOrientation / 90;
        this.processor =
                new ImageProcessor.Builder()
                        .add(new ResizeOp(scaleHei, scaleWid, ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR))
                        .add(new ResizeWithCropOrPadOp(imageSizeY, imageSizeX))
                        .add(new Rot90Op(numRotation))
                        .add(new GrayOp(imageSizeY, imageSizeX))
                        .add(getPreprocessNormalizeOp())
                        .build();
        processor.process(inputImageBuffer);
```

Run:

```
        int imageTensorIndex = 0;
        int[] imageShape = tflite.getInputTensor(imageTensorIndex).shape(); // {1, height, width, 3}
        if (imageSizeY != imageShape[1] || imageShape[1] == 0) { // imageSizeY changed
            tflite.resizeInput(imageTensorIndex, new int[]{1, imageSizeY, imageSizeX, 3}); //resize inputTensor
            for (int i = 0, count = tflite.getOutputTensorCount(); i < count; i++) { //recreate outputTensor
                DataType pDataType = tflite.getOutputTensor(i).dataType();
                if (pDataType == DataType.INT32) pDataType = DataType.FLOAT32;
                outputArr[i] = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(i == 0 ? new int[]{imageSizeY, imageSizeX} : new int[]{imageSizeX}, pDataType);
            }
        }
        Map<Integer, Object> outputMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0, cnt = outputArr.length; i < cnt; i++) { //rewind outputBuffer
            outputMap.put(i, outputArr[i].getBuffer().rewind());
            resizeOutputArr[i].getBuffer().rewind();
        }
        try {
            tflite.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(new Object[]{inputImageBuffer.getBuffer()}, outputMap);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        for (int i = 0, count = tflite.getOutputTensorCount(); i < count; i++) { //resize outputArr with new shape
            int[] shape = tflite.getOutputTensor(i).shape();
            outputArr[i].getBuffer().limit(computeFlatSize(shape) * DataType.FLOAT32.byteSize());
            resizeOutputArr[i].loadBuffer(outputArr[i].getBuffer(), shape);
            outputArr[i].getBuffer().clear();
            if (i == count - 1 && shape != null && shape[0] <= 0) return null;
        }
        return resizeOutputArr;
```

```
    protected static int computeFlatSize(@NonNull int[] shape) {
        SupportPreconditions.checkNotNull(shape, "Shape cannot be null.");
        int prod = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < shape.length; ++i) {
            prod *= shape[i];
        }
        return prod;
    }
```

I got blew Exception when there is no recognized object in the Bitmap:

```
W: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Internal error: Tensor hasn't been allocated.
W:     at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.buffer(Native Method)
W:     at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.buffer(Tensor.java:493)
W:     at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.copyTo(Tensor.java:264)
W:     at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.copyTo(Tensor.java:254)
W:     at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:170)
W:     at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(Interpreter.java:343)
W:     at com.fotric.irdetector.qf.tflite.Classifier.recognizeImage(Classifier.java:283)
```

This exception reduces the recognition performance, Someone help me, thanks!!!

Comment: This happens only when there is no recognized object?

Comment: @Farmaker Yes. It works well when there is at least one recognizable object

Comment: What's the model you're using? Is the output shape {224,320} correct? What about {1,224,320} or {1,224,320,3} ?

Comment: @TerryHeo doesn't work

Comment: *tflite.getOutputTensor(0).buffer()* Crashed When there is no object，and *tflite.getOutputTensor(0).shape()* Will not be refreshed, It is consistent with the shape obtained from the last effective recognition